# What are the current popular methods for Large Scale Gaussian Process Regression, and which of them are readily available in R?

Tags: r, regression, gaussian-process, large-data, variational-bayes

Vanilla Gaussian Process Regression requires $O(N^3)$ multiplications for estimation, $O(N^2)$ multiplications for prediction and it uses $O(N^2)$ memory where $N$ is the sample size, so it's not suitable for large data sets (assume I'm not using cloud computing here). However, dozens of different approaches to fit GPs to large (say, $N \geq= 10^5$) data sets have been presented in the last years, such as sparse GPs based on Variational Inference, local approximations, Patchwork Kriging, distributed GPs, etc.

Currently, which are the most popular, robust approaches (i.e., not necessarily state of the art, but robust enough that they can be used in a production environment), for which implementations are available in R?

Comment: This is not my area, but I've seen variational inference with inducing points in a several places. GPflow and GPy both seems pretty well used but are not in R.